# Echo php string into onclick as arg

Tags: php, onclick, arguments

I have an html onclick that calls a javascript function below:

```
onclick="addInventory(<?php echo $product['id']?>)"
```

Once I add a second arg which is a string, the function breaks, I believe
I have put it in quotes but I'm not sure how.

Breaks using:

```
onclick="addInventory(<?php echo $product['id']?>,<?php echo $product['name']?>)"
```

Comment: `<?php echo $product['id'] . $product['name']?>`

Comment: Good idea, i can parse the string using javascript with a delimiter like an underscore.

Comment: exactly, I was actually going to edit that too.

Comment: add single quote: `onclick="addInventory(<?php echo $product['id']?>,'<?php echo addslashes($product['name'])?>')"`

Comment: @fusion3k What if the product name is `Bob's Burger`?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, too right

Comment: @ceejayoz True about Bob's Burger, but then that will depend on what the OP has in their db to start with. And if coming from user input whether they'll allow quotes to start with. The question's unclear in that regard, but you have a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `json_encode`, when used on a variable, will properly escape it for JS usage.

```
onclick="addInventory(<?php echo json_encode($product['id'])?>,<?php echo json_encode($product['name'])?>)"
```

For example:

```
>>> json_encode('This is "my string" and it has some \'nasty\' characters in it!');
=> "This is \"my string\" and it has some 'nasty' characters in it!"
```

Comment: In this case you have to change html double quotes with single quotes.

Comment: @fusion3k Better to leave that up to `json_encode`. For a string, `json_encode` will wrap the output with double quotes by itself. For an integer, it will leave them off. You'll always wind up with a value safe to use in JavaScript.

Comment: my comment was not an objection, is a clarification

Comment: @fusion3k Right, but I'm saying leave the quotes off entirely. Let PHP's JSON encoding handle them as necessary.

Comment: @ceejayoz maybe I'm missing something, but pasting your code in html I obtain `onclick="addInventory(23,"myProduct")"` and onclick fails. I have to change it in `onclick='addInventory...` to make it work.

Comment: @fusion3k AH! Now I understand your meaning, sorry! You're absolutely right there.